# Reading multiple textfiles.txt and copying all duplicate lines to a new textfile.txt in VB .net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

FIRST PROBLEM:
I am looking for an easiest way to read multiple text files at one time and extract all the duplicate lines from each text file and copy those duplicate lines to a new text file with headings representing name of parent text file. I am dealing with more than 20 text files at a time and it is a mess to go through each one by one. Secondly, I am dealing with large / heavy file (more or less 30,000 lines in each file) .. I am currently using a program with "Stream Reader" and "Stream Writer" and I prefer to have the same approach for my understanding. OR any new and easy way is Welcome !!
SECOND PROBLEM:
I want to compare 2 text files and get the duplicate lines on to a new text file. I don't want to remove/delete/overwrite: Just to copy them across to a new text file. 
Please use openfiledialog and savefiledialog for the files.

Thanks a lot in advance.
 Best Regards
VB_Learner

```
 Dim Dim optxtfile As New OpenFileDialog
    optxtfile.RestoreDirectory = True
    optxtfile.Multiselect = False
    optxtfile.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    optxtfile.FilterIndex = 1
    optxtfile.ShowDialog()
    If (Not optxtfile.FileName = Nothing) Then
        Dim lines As New List(Of String)
        Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(optxtfile.FileName)
            While sr.Peek <> -1
                Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()
                Dim isNew As Boolean = True
                For Each dupl As String In lines
                    If (dupl = line) Then isNew = False
                Next
                If (isNew) Then lines.Add(sr.ReadLine())
            End While
        End Using
        Dim svDir As String
        If (My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(optxtfile.FileName)) Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(optxtfile.FileName)
            svDir = optxtfile.filename
            Dim svtxtfile As New SaveFileDialog
            svtxtfile.RestoreDirectory = True
            svtxtfile.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt"
            svtxtfile.FilterIndex = 1
            svtxtfile.ShowDialog()
            If (svtxtfile.FileName = Nothing) Then
                svDir = optxtfile.FileName
            Else
                svDir = svtxtfile.FileName
            End If
        End If
        Using write2text As New System.IO.StreamWriter(svDir)
            For Each line As String In lines
                write2text.WriteLine(line)
            Next
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. One problem per question only. 2. Show what you have tried so far. You need to provide some effort. Noone will code this completely for you.

Comment: oh .. im sorry... I forgot to post the code here... !!

Comment: Please consider the second problem as well """" SECOND PROBLEM: I want to compare 2 text files and get the duplicate lines on to a new text file. I don't want to remove/delete/overwrite: Just to copy them across to a new text file. Please use openfiledialog and savefiledialog for the files."""